# CURL function returns Erron Number: 56 Error String:Received HTTP code 406 from proxy after CONNECT

Tags: php, codeigniter, curl

The purpose of this CURL is to generate a token for the user. If the token is returned correctly, then the user can be able to access all the menus. If not, the user will get a logout from the application.

```
    $ch = curl_init();'
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, 'Proxy IP');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($data));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 15);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
```

What I am missing here??

**NOTE:** The server I am connecting to is in the AWS cloud, and we already have a server which is outside the cloud, and the curl is working fine and the generated token is receiving. I am not sure what the problem here is.

Comment: add CURLOPT_VERBOSE: ```$stderrh=tmpfile();
curl_setopt_array($ch,array(CURLOPT_VERBOSE=>1,CURLOPT_STDERR=>$stderrh));
$result=curl_exec($ch);
/* https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=76268 */
rewind($stderrh); 
$stderr=stream_get_contents($stderrh);
fclose($stderrh);
echo $stderr;
``` and show the verbose log. in any case, it suggest there's something strange with the `Accept: ` HTTP header (which the CURLOPT_VERBOSE log would show)

Comment: I have voted to close this question as `Needs details` - because it does. add the CURLOPT_VERBOSE information i requested, and i will retract my close vote.

Comment: I am implementing CURLOPT_VERBOSE as you said @hanshenrik once done I will update you

Comment: depends on how you run the php code. if you are running php from php-fpm/apache/nginx/iis/lighthttpd, then you probably need all that tmpfile() stuff, otherwise the CURLOPT_VERBOSE log will go to your php error log instead of the browser. if you are running php from php-cli, then you only need CURLOPT_VERBOSE

Comment: *   Trying 172.31.13.141...
        * Connected to 172.31.13.141 (172.31.13.141) port 80 (#0)
        * Establish HTTP proxy tunnel to ssoaws2.enoahprojects.com:443
        > CONNECT ssoaws2.enoahprojects.com:443 HTTP/1.1 Host: 
        ssoaws2.enoahprojects.com:443  Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
        < HTTP/1.1 406 Not Acceptable
        < Date: Mon, 26 Sep 2022 15:40:48 GMT
        < Server: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
        < Content-Length: 0
        < Content-Type: application/json
        < * Received HTTP code 406 from proxy after CONNECT
        * Closing connection 0

Comment: This is the response I have got while after added the verbose.

Comment: $fp = fopen("php://temp/maxmemory:$fiveMBs", 'r+'); curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, '***.**.**.***:**'); curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($data)); curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields); curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 0); curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1); curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR, $fp); curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 0); curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 15); $result = curl_exec($ch); rewind($fp); $verbose = stream_get_contents($fp); echo $verbose;

Comment: that log indicates that `ssoaws2.enoahprojects.com` does *NOT* have a HTTP proxy on port 443. are you sure the proxy is on ssoaws2.enoahprojects.com ? are you sure the proxy is on port 443? are you sure the proxy is a HTTP proxy (rather than a SOCKS proxy?) - 1 of those assumptions are probably wrong. (either you have the wrong domain, OR you have the wrong port, OR you have the wrong proxy protocol)

Comment: I have checked with my Admin Team regarding the above questions and they saying    
                the proxy is on ssoaws2.enoahprojects.com : YES
  sure the proxy is on port 443 : YES
  proxy is a HTTP proxy : YES

Comment: And one more thing the Proxy IP is same as the Domain IP is there any problem with that @hanshenrik.